# Is it bad practice to select upstream servers based upon the HTTP method?

Tags: http, reverse-proxy

I'm wondering if it is bad practice to have a reverse proxy that selects the upstream server depending on the HTTP method used?

The background is that I have an abitrary web server that handles `POST` requests with some logic behind. The same resources also contain static content, that can be retrieved using `GET`. After some benchmarking I realized that nginx would handle the static content way faster than my abitrary web server doing this.

I checked the option to forward incoming requests internally using nginx, which is feasible.

But this would lead to the fact that different servers would serve a distinct resource, only depending on issuing a `GET` or `POST`, including different header fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not bad practice, partitioning the tasks by the nature of the task is perfectly fine, as long as you don't need to store persistent per-user-session data on the server.